# Eclipse big cross icon meaning?

Tags: eclipse

I am seeing this for the first time, could anyone tell me what this actually means?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Go to the "Problems" pane, is there something there?

Comment: Yes, but those errors are not referring to the big cross. They are some other issues (which might be happening due to the big cross).

Comment: have you installed any plugins recently?

Comment: Are you using any kind of source control with an eclipse plugin? It might be a removed file (see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/State but you seem to have a different icon scheme).

Comment: I am using svn yes. I guess you are right, I had deleted the folder and then recreated it, then SVN might have gotten confused and hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's "Scheduled for deletion".

The term for such things is "Label Decoration", so you can search for "Eclipse Subversive label decoration" or "Subclipse label decoration" and see what comes up.